# How to convert System.Collections.Generics.IENumerable <String> to string

Tags: c#, file, type-conversion

I want to convert a variable obtained from a  Directory.EnumerateFiles method to a string . This Variable Contains a set of file paths  of folders that contain the FileServer.config in them

```
 var foundFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootDirectory, "fileserver.config", 

    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var RepositoryName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(foundFiles));
```

Here string rootDirectory is a particular path

Any way I can achieve this ?

As per my current implementation I get the error "Cannot convert System.Collections.Generics.IENumerable  to string " underlined Right under the foundFiles variable.

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple files named `fileserver.config` located in different child directories?

Comment: Why are you using ` Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(foundFiles));`? If you want a parent directory's path you might want to use `DirectoryInfo.ParentDirectory.FullPath` instead to be clearer.

Comment: My requirement is to Display the name of the folders which has this "fileserver.config"

Comment: But what should happen if there are multiple folders that all contain a file with that name?

Comment: Ideally I want to Display the Folder name of the Folders that have this fileserver.config inside of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My original answer

Originally I thought that you only expected there to be a single file named `fileserver.config` and you wanted the path to that file - which can be done using `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
using System.Linq;

String firstFileMatch = Directory
    .EnumerableFiles( rootDirectory, "fileserver.config" )
    .FirstOrDefault();

if( firstFileMatch == null )
{
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
}

return Path.GetDirectoryName( Path.GetDirectoryName( fileFirstMatch ) );
```

### New answer

In a follow-up comment you said you wanted to print all of the files - so that's straightforward too, using `String.Join`:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<String> fileNames = new DirectoryInfo( rootDirectoryPath )
    .EnumerableFiles( "fileServer.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories )
    .Select( fi => fi.Directory.FullName )
    .Select( dirPath => dirPath.Substring( rootDirectoryPath.Length ) );

String allNames = String.Join( "\r\n\r\n", fileNames );
MessageBox.Show( allNames );
```

Comment: but this converts the firstFileMatch  into a char isnt it ?

Comment: anyway I can simoly convert System.Collections.Generics.IENumerable <String> to a string

Comment: @Devss No. I think you're getting confused with the unrelated fact that a `String` is `IEnumerable<Char>`, but an `IEnumerable<String>` is not a single string value, but can be multiple string values - as I said, it will return the paths of all files in `rootDirectory` named `fileserver.config` - there can be more than 1 file with that name.

Comment: Any Solution you can recommend cause im really stuck here , I want to print out those Directories using a Message box by adding them all together using string builder , which Is why I need it to be in String format

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your answer is great but the output it gives is the absolute path of the folders which have this .config file but my requirement is to get Just the Last Folder Name of it ?
For example now it shows ,
D:\RepositoryHomeTest\folder1\fileserver.config

but what I ant is just "folder1"

Comment: Sorry to trouble but fi.ParentDirectory.FullName gives an error saying FileInfo does not contain a definition for fi.ParentDirectory.FullName

What exactly do you mean by Parent Directory here ?

Comment: @Devss Please use your sense of curiosity to explore the `FileInfo` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.directory?view=netframework-4.8